# Installing python module "undefined symbol: PyString_FromStringAndSize"

Tags: python, ubuntu, module

I have different python versions installed on my ubuntu machine. The default version is 2.7.

I'm trying to install nfqueue module for version 3.4:

```
#apt-get install libnetfilter-queue-dev

#pip3 install NetfilterQueue
```

When I try to test if it is correctly installed I get this error:

```
>>>import netfilterqueue
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/netfilterqueue.cpython-34m.so:undefined symbol: PyString_FromStringAndSize
```

Has any one an idea what would be the problem??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function `PyString_FromStringAndSize` doesn't exist in python 3.x... you need to make sure you're installing the correct nfqueue module

Comment: How can I verify that?

Comment: Is there a way to verify that I install the right version of nfqueue for python 3?